# Untracked Working tree file on git command

Tags: git

I am completely newbie on git and Linux , but I have to do something. We have a step by step procedure which is done before without any problem. Today I have to do it from scratch but this time when I am using this command

```
 git fetch --tags  path/afiletofetch.bu
 git merge FETCH_HEAD
```

I'll receive this error message

```
Untracked Working tree file /BEE/V/adm/Start/scripte/tis_end would be overwritten by merge
```

what should I do? And what should I check to resolve the error?

Comment: Before merging, commit changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means you have something like this

```
A --- B
 \    L HEAD
  \
   \- C
      L FETCH_HEAD
```

so that you're currently in commit `B`, you currently have on your filesystem the file `tis_end`, and this file isn't tracked by Git on this commit.

However, this file *is* tracked by git on commit `C` -and it likely isn't the same version as the one you currently have.

To be safe, git is refusing to merge because it would overwrite your local version of `tis_end`.

The solution depends on what you want to do with this file. In particular you could:

- Delete this file if you don't care about your local modifications
- Commit this file before merging (it may lead to conflicts on this file during the merge, but at least you won't loose your work)

To commit it, you should do something like:

```
git add BEE/V/adm/Start/scripte/tis_end
git status #To make sure you're going to commit what you're expecting
git commit -m "Adding tis_end"
```

It will lead to something like

```
A --- B -- D
 \         L HEAD
  \
   \- C
      L FETCH_HEAD
```

where `D` is the new commit, with this file tracked.

(Either way, you could do a backup of this file first: better safe than sorry)

Comment: how can i commit the file?

Comment: how can i commit the changes on Branch B?

Comment: I edited my post. i was fetching another file, so why should commit tis_end. i haven't done anything with tis_end

Comment: I don't know what led you to this issue. Anyway it's rather easy to confirm this diagnostic: just compare successively the state of the file on HEAD and FETCH_HEAD

Comment: well i did what you said but it started to repeat the message for other files which some of them is linux files